# HP DL180 G6 - Are 6G/s speeds obtainable?

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, sas

I have a DL180 G6 server with 12x 2Tb 6G/s SAS drives. I was only getting 3G/s reported. I then went and purchased a P410 controller with 512 Meg cache and battery.

I loaded up the drives with Server 2008 R2 and then 2012 R2. The SAS drives are still only showing up as 3G/s drives.

I have these EXACT SAME SAS drives using a P410i internal controller (almost the same controller) on a DL385 G7 machines and they are all reporting 6G/s.

Am I missing something here? May I get 6G/s on the DL180 G6 machines?

Thank you so very kindly for your time and consideration of my question.

Your friend in Virginia, Paul L.

ps. Sorry for posting a question as a reply on another thread.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any 12-bay servers to test with right now, but understand that there's an expander backplane in between your disks and your controller.

From the HP SSA utility:

```
   Enclosure SEP (Vendor ID HP, Model DL18xG6BP) 248
      Device Number: 248
      Firmware Version: 2.20
      WWID: 50001C1071540013
      Port: 2I
      Box: 1
      Vendor ID: HP
      Model: DL18xG6BP

   SEP (Vendor ID PMCSIERA, Model  SRC 8x6G) 249
      Device Number: 249
      Firmware Version: RevC
      WWID: 500143800532B39F
      Vendor ID: PMCSIERA
      Model:  SRC 8x6G
```

Please make sure your firmware is up-to-date. The only 12-bay DL180 G6 server I have actually contains 12 x 300GB 3G SAS disks in it. My 8-bay DL180 G6 servers are all linked up at 6Gbps.

However, 6G won't make a difference for the disks you describe, so the link speed really doesn't matter. Nearline disks aren't capable of actual 6Gbps transfers.

Answer (score 0):

From SA firmware changelog:
"HP Smart Array P812 controller onboard expander firmware was updated to version 3.12 to enforce 3Gbps SATA connection speeds which is the maximum supported SATA data rate on HP Smart Array P212, P410, P410i, P411, P711m, P712m, and P812 controllers."